# There is any issue if my widget_test.dart file under test directory showing error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

This image showing my widget_test.dart file. During moving a file from my recent project to a new one these errors occur.But my project running smoothly. I want to ask if delete this file or remains the same as errors there is any issue occurred in the future in this project?

Comment: It's the default test file that is generated from `flutter create`.  You can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete that file. It is a file default test file created by flutter for testing purpose. but you can create another one in future ,if you want to perform tests on your code.